# Github actions trigger build on tags and branches

Tags: typescript, tags, github-actions, npm-publish

I have typescript project in repository.
The release policy is that we publish package from  **master** branch to **next** npm tag, and we have dedicated branch called **release** that publishes to **latest** npm tag.
I want to optimize solution and only run it when new tag is pushed to one of the branches.

1. If tag is pushed to **master** branch i want to run a job that publishes to **next** npm tag
2. If tag is pushed to **release** branch i want to run a job that publishes to **latest** npm tag.

The problem is that github context only contains ref variable that is always equals to tag name no matter which branch i push into. I have no way to find out on which branch im running.
How can i sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger GHA for specific branches and tags like:

```
on:
   push:
     branches:
       - master
   pull_request:
       types:
          - opened
          - synchronize
       tags:
          - next
```

in between steps you can add a check like to verify your branch name:

```
if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
```